# Generate array of objects from two arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got 2 arrays:

```
var arrToObjContent = ["DAYOFWEEK","ITEM","QTY","DATEOFPURCHASE","CITY"]
var dayOfWeek="["SUN","MON","TUE","WED","THU","FRI","SAT"]
```

I've been trying to create an object array using the above two arrays that looks like this:

```
{
"DAYOFWEEK":"SUN"
"ITEM":"",
"QTY":"",
"DATEOFPURCHASE":"",
"CITY":""
},    {
"DAYOFWEEK":"MON"
"ITEM":"",
"QTY":"",
"DATEOFPURCHASE":"",
"CITY":""
},{
"DAYOFWEEK":"TUE"
"ITEM":"",
"QTY":"",
"DATEOFPURCHASE":"",
"CITY":""
},{
"DAYOFWEEK":"WED"
"ITEM":"",
"QTY":"",
"DATEOFPURCHASE":"",
"CITY":""
},{
"DAYOFWEEK":"THU"
"ITEM":"",
"QTY":"",
"DATEOFPURCHASE":"",
"CITY":""
},{
"DAYOFWEEK":"FRI"
"ITEM":"",
"QTY":"",
"DATEOFPURCHASE":"",
"CITY":""
},{
"DAYOFWEEK":"SAT"
"ITEM":"",
"QTY":"",
"DATEOFPURCHASE":"",
"CITY":""
}
```

Is there a jQuery/JavaScript built-in function that I can pass two arrays to & get the output as above?

Comment: that's kind of up to you to find out. You have to fairly straight forward bits of data, and a clear description of what you want, you should be able to write some code that achieves what you want, even if it doesn't use "the best possible functions" to do so. Start with just iterating over your array of days, and doing something "for each entry in that array".

Comment: No, there's no built-in function that does this. It's a simple matter to write a nested loop that does it.

Comment: if `dayOfWeek` is supposed to be an array, you shouldn't have `"` at the beginning of the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really not that hard, here you go:

```
var arrToObjContent = ["DAYOFWEEK","ITEM","QTY","DATEOFPURCHASE","CITY"],
    dayOfWeek = ["SUN","MON","TUE","WED","THU","FRI","SAT"],
    i=0,
    z,
    arrToObjLength = arrToObjContent.length,
    dayOfWeekLength = dayOfWeek.length,
    jsonObj = {},
    newObj,
    key,
    value;

for(;i<dayOfWeekLength;i++){
    newObj = {};
    for(z=0;z<arrToObjLength;z++){
        key = arrToObjContent[z];

        if(key === "DAYOFWEEK") {
            value = dayOfWeek[i];
        }   
        else {
            value = "";
        }
        newObj[key] = value;
    }
    jsonObj[i] = newObj;
}

console.table(jsonObj);
```

FYI, you had some syntax error in your original posted code.

Comment: Thank you Amir. This is quite clear. The problem I had while writing this up was in the mapping part. Cool. Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in function to do this, but it is fairly straightforward to do on your own.

```
var arrToObjContent = ["DAYOFWEEK","ITEM","QTY","DATEOFPURCHASE","CITY"];
var dayOfWeek=["SUN","MON","TUE","WED","THU","FRI","SAT"];
dayOfWeek.map((x) => {
    var obj = {};
    arrToObjContent.forEach((y) => { obj[y] = (y === "DAYOFWEEK")? x : ""; });
    return obj;
  });
```